# add a matlab gui to a powerpoint presentation

Tags: matlab, user-interface, powerpoint

I am curious if I can add a matlab gui to a powerpoint presentation. Either within the presentation or a link to open up matlab.

I call this function and it will open the figure then immediately close it.

```
Private Sub click_Click()
Call RunFile("new_control_pan", "C:\Users\mhaartman\Documents\PANE_golden2\PANE_golden\code")
End Sub

Sub RunFile(FILENAME As String, Optional FilePath As String)
Dim MATLAB As Object
Dim Result As String
Dim Command As String
Dim MATLABWasNotRunning As Boolean
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Set Up
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Connect to the automation server.
' MATLAB becomes a MATLAB handle to the running instance
' of MATLAB.
On Error Resume Next ' Defer error trapping
MATLAB = GetObject(, "matlab.application") 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MATLABWasNotRunning = True
Set MATLAB = CreateObject("matlab.application")
Err.Clear ' Clear Err object in case error occurred.
End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Do the Work
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Not IsMissing(FilePath) And Not FilePath = "" Then
Command = "cd('" + FilePath + "')"
Result = MATLAB.Execute(Command)
End If
Command = FILENAME
Result = MATLAB.Execute(Command)

'Result = MsgBox("Done", vbOkayOnly, "Click when done")
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it is possible with ActiveX..but I don't have the Developer view in powerpoint...any way aroudn this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could take a look at [Calling MATLAB from PowerPoint](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19597-calling-matlab-from-powerpoint).This submission on the File Exchange may be out of date, as it was created a few years ago. But the latest versions of MATLAB continue in general to offer a COM interface, which can be called from PowerPoint. It may need some updating, but I'm sure any issues are correctable.

Comment: I looked at that. Not sure that is applicable to latest Matlab and latest PowerPoint. I get errors when trying to call the function described

Comment: The submission on the File Exchange may be out of date, as it was created a few years ago. But the latest versions of MATLAB continue in  general to offer a COM interface, which can be called from PowerPoint. It may need some updating, but I'm sure any issues are correctable. What error are you getting, and when?

Comment: Can you edit your original answer so I can give you points--seemed to work..just some issues with VB